# changing timezone does not reflect in python's datetime.now() function

Tags: python, windows, datetime, timezone

I've been using this code to change the timezone in my windows os. It works fine but when I get the new date and time via `datetime.now()` it gives me the date and time when it was still not changed. I have to re-run the script for it to get the right date and time.Thanks

```
def adjustPrivilege( priv ):
    try:
        flags = ntsecuritycon.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | ntsecuritycon.TOKEN_QUERY
        htoken =  win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), flags)
        id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, priv)
        newPrivileges = [(id, ntsecuritycon.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
        win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, newPrivileges)
    except:
        pass
# Enable the privilege
adjustPrivilege(win32security.SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME)

# Set the timezone
win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation((-480,u'China Standard Time',(2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),0,u'China Standard Time',(2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),-0))
time.sleep(5)
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Are you really wanting to change the time zone of the whole machine? Or just the time zone used within your python code?

Comment: @MattJohnson I'm changing the timezone before connecting to time server using ntplib. Since I think ntplib depends on machines timezone for the correct date and time return.

Comment: NTP is always based on UTC. Time zone adjustments are done after the fact.

Comment: It seems changing the timezone is unnecessary in your specific case. But it might be useful for future visitors to find out how to do `os.environ['TZ'] = ':Asia/Shanghai'; time.tzset()` on Windows. Have you tried to change the timezone *before* `time` or `datetime` modules are imported? Have you tried to `reload()` them? Does [`tzlocal.get_localzone()`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzlocal) return the new timezone?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I've tried importing time/datetime before changing timezone. Reload datetime, time and ntplib and still the same problem. tzlocal.get_localzone() returns correct timezone when modules are reloaded

Comment: if `tz = get_localzone()` returns correct timezone then try `datetime.now(tz)` to get the current time in your local timezone.